# when to free resource - weird situation

Tags: c

I code on some device.
The flow is usually like this:

```
int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
   postMainMenu();
}
```

`postMainMenu()` defined as:

```
void postMainMenu(void)
{
    while(1)
    {
        // Present user with options
        s32 res = MessageBox("Menu", "1- Download\r2- Settings", 0, KEY_MASK_1|KEY_MASK_2);

        // Which key did the user press?
        if(res ==  KEY_1)
          showDownloadDialog();
        else if (res ==  KEY_2)
          showSettingsDialog();
    }
    return;
}
```

You can notice actually program never quits, once it enters `postMainMenu` right?
In a way that is correct, because there is single app running on this device, so the
user can only quit, once he just turns off the device. That is how it works now.

But I had such question, say I allocate dynamic memory inside `postMainMenu()` - then when do I free it?
Or should I leave it like that, and rely that after user just turns of the device, that memory will be "freed" - **and it won't damage anything, since the device was turned off anyway.**

Comment: You free the memory (or any resource) when you no longer need it. If it's something you allocate once (outside the loop) why not simply define it as a stack variable? Then you don't have to worry about it. If you do the allocation inside the loop, you can maybe still define it as a stack variable, otherwise free the memory before the loop starts over its iteration.

Comment: well just present user turn off option and do save and etc. Have you never noticed there is shutdown option on Windows,Linux and..

Comment: It depends on the scope and use of the object you create.  If it is only used in postmainmemu() then free() the object just before the return from the function.  If you don't and the pointer does not have global scope, so it can be reused in the function or free-ed somewhere else, you create a memory leak.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Probably I will want to create it *outside* the loop and use in other .c files too (maybe it will be global var). ps. so far I was using stack variables, but I thought I might need to use dynamic arrays - defined outside the loop as I said

Comment: If you want to pass the object around to other functions, you can still define it as a stack variable, just pass a pointer to it to the functions that need it using the address-of operator `&`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: true but if I want dynamic array I think I can't avoid malloc and etc. But again, then comes the question when to free it? like I said as one can see postMainMenu never returns. But is it a big deal if it remains like this? Like I said, the ONLY way user usually quits postMainMenu is using Turn Off button of device, and is the memory created in such case, big deal?

Comment: Since you have tagged the question with C++, whenever you want to use "dynamic arrays" you should think [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Ok i have removed the tag, since this is more C

Comment: How about just `malloc`, and `realloc` when needed? Then as the `realloc` calls will handle freeing the old memory areas you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: Joachim, yes but still somewhere that memory needs to be freed right? even if realloc was used? But in my program it is not possible if variable was defined outside the loop.

Comment: Most operating systems will free all of a process allocated memory when the process exits, and it doesn't matter *how* it exits (voluntarily, being killed or something else). So in your use case you probably don't have to worry about it.

Comment: yes that is why I accepted below answer. but thank you for your help anyway. ps. not sure what operating system is on this device (if there is any, but anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful that you're not leaking memory during the execution of your program, *especially* for what sounds like a very limited embedded device that likely doesn't have much RAM. Arguably it would make for good program code to free everything you allocate, so that this is not a worry.

But, practically speaking, does it matter whether you have memory left over at the termination of your program, if the power goes off at that time? No, it doesn't.

Comment: "But, practically speaking, does it matter whether you have memory left over at the termination of your program, if the power goes off at that time? No, it doesn't." --- This is exactly my question. If you look once again at the question, that's the kind of situation I have, isn't it? (otherwise in other places I use stack variables)

Comment: @user2568508 - stop worrying so much, you're overthinking stuff.

Comment: @MartinJames: You also have a point, but like Lightness Races in Orbit said, I think practically it is not big deal. Because even if I leak memory above, it means user clicked "Turn Off" device button, isn't it?

Comment: @user2568508: Yes, which is why I wrote that in my answer.